# Objects in List<T> reference same value

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list of custom objects `List<Slot>`
Each Object Slot has an array of Gene[]

Object slot

```
public class Slot
{
    private Gene[] _genes;
    private int _fitness;
    //...

    public Slot(int count)
    {
        _genes = InitializeArray<Gene>(count);
        Fitness = 0;
    }

    public Gene[] getChromosomes()
    {
        return Genes; //getter method
    }

    //Helper to init array
    static T[] InitializeArray<T>(int length) where T : new()
    {
        T[] array = new T[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
        {
            array[i] = new T();
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Object Gene

```
public class Gene
{
    private DateTime _date;
    private int _tcode;
    private byte _availabe;  
    private byte _duty;  
    private int _fitness;
    //...

    public Gene()
    {
        _fitness = 0;
    }
}
```

Main

```
private List<Slot> slotsList = new List<Slot>();
//...
//...
private void init_population(int lchromeSize, int lpopulationSize)
{
    slotsList.Clear();                      
    Gene[] lstGene = InitializeArray<Gene>(lchromeSize);

    //For all slots
    for (int i = 0; i < tempInt; i++)
    {
        //for all genes

        for (int ii = 0; ii < lchromeSize; ii++)
        {
            //assign values to local variables 
            // and :
            lstGene[ii].Date = ldate;
            lstGene[ii].Tcode = lteacherCode;                    
            lstGene[ii].Availabe = lavailable;
            lstGene[ii].Duty = tempDuty;
            lstGene[ii].Fitness = 0;

        }
        //End ii For

        //Add the genes to slotsList
        Slot itemtoadd = new Slot(lchromeSize);
        itemtoadd.setChromosomes(lstGene);
        slotsList.Add(itemtoadd);
    }
}
```

The problem is that in every single Slot the Genes are identical and they reference the last lstGene[] that has been added to slotsList.

Where did I mess up it again ?

Comment: You are modifying the same array reference. You  should initialize a new Gene pool in every iteration of `i`.

Comment: You are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move this line:

```
Gene[] lstGene = InitializeArray<Gene>(lchromeSize);
```

to be **inside** the `for (int i = ..` loop. You are now re-using the same array for every slot - which is what you see.

Answer (score 3):

You should create new array for each itemtoadd.

```
//For all slots
for (int i = 0; i < tempInt; i++)
{
    //for all genes
    Gene[] lstGene = InitializeArray<Gene>(lchromeSize);
    for (int ii = 0; ii < lchromeSize; ii++)
    {
        //assign values to local variables 
        // and :
        lstGene[ii].Date = ldate;
        lstGene[ii].Tcode = lteacherCode;                    
        lstGene[ii].Availabe = lavailable;
        lstGene[ii].Duty = tempDuty;
        lstGene[ii].Fitness = 0;

    }
    //End ii For

    //Add the genes to slotsList
    Slot itemtoadd = new Slot(lchromeSize);
    itemtoadd.setChromosomes(lstGene);
    slotsList.Add(itemtoadd);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you initialize your **Gene[] lstGene** inside a loop? Otherwise you are still referencing the same array over and over again if I am not mistaken